# why react router dom throwing hooks Invalid hook call error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

React router throwing this warning. even did what documentation says.

**Warning:** Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

in app.js i did this

```
     import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
      function App() {
          return (
          <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<div>Home page</div>} />
           <Route path="/about" element={<div>aBout page</div>} />
          </Routes>
         </BrowserRouter>
          );
           }

         export default App;
```

[image: this is what error it throws]

Comment: What is the version of your `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: The error/code stacktrace is saying that `React` is null in the `BrowserRouter` code on line 151 (i.e. where it's trying to use `React.useRef`. What versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed? From the project's root directory run `npm list react react-router react-router-dom` and report back the installed versions. Can you also edit your question to include a more complete code example? How is `App` component being rendered? How are you running the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its about you are calling a div element instead of a React component.

Try converting to this:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
       <Route index element={<HomePage />}> 
         //index means it is the first page you are gonna encounter.
         <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
       </Route>
      </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

And make sure you've created `HomePage` and `AboutPage` components and imported them.

Comment: Yes i have also used react components but get the same error.